# More accurate approach than k-mean clustering

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, k-means, biological-neural-network

In Radial Basis Function Network (RBF Network), all the prototypes (center vectors of the RBF functions) in the hidden layer are chosen. This step can be performed in several ways:

- Centers can be randomly sampled from some set of examples.
- Or, they can be determined using k-mean clustering.

One of the approaches for making an intelligent selection of prototypes is to perform k-mean clustering on our training set and to use the cluster centers as the prototypes.
All we know that k-mean clustering is caracterized by its simplicity (it is fast) but not very accurate.

That is why I would like know what is the other approach that can be more accurate than k-mean clustering?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several k-means variations exist: k-medians, Partitioning Around Medoids, Fuzzy C-Means Clustering, Gaussian mixture models trained with expectation-maximization algorithm, k-means++, etc.

I use PAM (Partitioning around Medoid) in order to be more accurate when my dataset contain some "outliers" (noise with value which are very different to the others values) and I don't want the centers to be influenced by this data. In the case of PAM a center is called a Medoid.

Comment: Please can you give me the matlab code that you used ? :D

Comment: And I think that PAM is very close to the k-mean clustering in terms of implementation . Does this is true ?

Comment: I don't know the details of implementation but I think it is true because it is based on the same principle than k-means. I don't use Matlab, I use R and it is [implemented into R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/cluster/html/pam.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a more statistical approach to cluster analysis, called the [Expectation-Maximization Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm). It uses statistical analysis to determine clusters. This is probably a better approach when you have a lot of data regarding your cluster centroids and training data.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Clusters_and_clusterings) link also lists several other clustering algorithms out there in the wild. Obviously, some are better than others, depending on the amount of data you have and/or the type of data you have.

There is a wonderful course on Udacity, Intro to Artificial Intelligence, where one lesson is dedicated to unsupervised learning, and Professor Thrun explains some clustering algorithms in very great detail. I highly recommend that course!

I hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

In terms of K-Means, you can run it on your sample a number of times (say, 100) and then choose the clustering (and by consequence the centroids) that has the smallest K-Means criterion output (the sum of the square Euclidean distances between each entity and its respective centroid).

You can also use some initialization algorithms (the intelligent K-Means comes to mind, but you can also google for K-Means++). You can find a very good review of K-Means in a paper by AK Jain called Data clustering: 50 years beyond K-means.

You can also check hierarchical methods, such as the Ward method.